# How to update a column in a database with array values?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, database, ms-access

I have an `int` array with some values inside it, and its size is unknown (filled dynamically). I want to update a column in a database with this array (i.e. the column m of nth record in the database will be updated with nth element of the array). How can I achieve this? Should I update each record of the table in a separate sql similar to as follows:

```
for(int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
{
    string sqlCommand = "UPDATE TABLENAME SET THECOLUMN = " + array[i] + " WHERE ID = " + (i+1);
    // Execute the command
}
```

, or is there a more efficient or simplery way to do it?

<sub>PS: I am using ACCESS Database, connecting it to a (ASP.NET) website via C#</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it in one round trip

```
StringBuilder command = new StringBuilder();
for(int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++) {
    command.Append("UPDATE TABLENAME SET THECOLUMN = " + array[i] + 
                " WHERE ID = " + (i+1) + ";");
}
// Execute the command HERE
```

"Back and forths" to the database are fairly expensive, so you usually want your communications to be "chunky not chatty".